# Error parsing xhtml since '<' character inside the string that is meant to be uploaded to website

Tags: python, html, python-requests, httprequest, xhtml

I am using python to upload a string into a website using requests.put() method but I am getting an error while trying to upload that string onto the website. The error is in the form of a parsing error which states:

```
Error parsing xhtml: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) in content after '<' (malformed start element)
```

I understand why it is showing since I have the '<' in my string and since this is html code the parser is looking for corresponding '>' without knowing that this is part of string. I tried escaping with a backslash ('<') and also ('\<') but it does not work as then I get a syntax error which states incorrect use of escape character.

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

example_string = '<p><strong>Into managed branch from 2021-3-1 to 2021-5-3</strong></p><table><colgroup><col style=\\"width: 115.0px;\\" /><col style=\\"width: 95.0px;\\" /><col style=\\"width: 58.0px;\\" /><col style=\\"width: 105.0px;\\" /><col style=\\"width: 110.0px;\\" /><col style=\\"width: 215.0px;\\" /><col style=\\"width: 215.0px;\\" /></colgroup><tbody><tr><td><p>This is going < to print</p></td></tr></tbody></table><p class=\\"auto-cursor-target\\"><br /></p>'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"id":"534756378","type":"page", "title":"GL_Engine Output","space":{"key":"CSSFW"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"' + example_string + '","representation":"storage"}}, "version":{"number":109}}'
json.loads(data)
print("JSON loads successful")
response = requests.put('https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/534756378', headers=headers, data=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('svc-Auto@ai.com', 'AIengineering1@ai'))
print(response)
print(response.json())
```

Note the '<' is in my string "This is going < to print" further along example_string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the `<` sign with `&lt;` (less-than sign).

```
<p>This is going &lt; to print</p>
```

The browser renders this [HTML entity](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/) as `<`.